# Solved - Magento 1.9 - IWD OPC - How can I display Base Grand Total on the checkout page?

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I am running a Magento 1 website with version 4.2.2 of IWD One Page Checkout.

I have just modified the website to display a currency selector.

What this module does not appear to display is the Base Grand Total on the checkout page i.e.

> Your credit card will be charged for £00.00

I have looked at modifying the following file but cannot find a variable to add in

> \app\design\frontend\ultimo\xxx\template\opc\wrapper.phtml

The Grand Total is displayed by:

`<?php echo Mage::helper('opc')->getGrandTotal()?>`

Anybody?

Answer (score 0):

After further digging around I found the answer I needed and added the following PHP code - I'll leave it here in case anyone else should need it:

```
// Degug code
// print_r(Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getData());

$baseGrandTotal = number_format(Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getBaseGrandTotal(), 2);
$symbol=Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency('GBP')->getSymbol();
echo "<p>Your credit card will be charged for " . $symbol . $baseGrandTotal . "</p>";
```